# Check if method "return null" and is @Nullable

Tags: java, null, static-analysis, findbugs

Can I make Findbugs, or any other code analyser, check if a method that can return `null` is annotated as `@Nullable`?

That't the case I would like to check:

```
// Third party library
class Foo
{
    // Static test should fail because it's not annotated as @Nullable
    String get()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful link, but not really a duplicate. I would like to analyse whole codebase that I use (including legacy code), and not just check it on the fly in IDEA.

Comment: Check my last comment to my answer, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the current tooling cannot do that out of the box, including IntelliJ. You will have to write a custom FindBugs check. FindBugs has some logic to support nullness analysis.

The reason for that is that you are trying to reverse-engineer the contract of the method. Nullness annotations are part of the contract, so they cannot, and should not be inferred from the code. There is no way, not even in theory, to tell if the programmer *wanted* the method to return `null` values or if that is a programming mistake. Depending on that, you would have to fix the code by either adding the `@Nullable` annotation, or by changing the method body so that it cannot return `null` (and probably adding `@Nonnull`).

FindBugs features some [annotations](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html) that you can use to specify nullness defaults on a package level. It will then check that all methods of classes in that package conform to your default. If you didn't do that, FindBugs assumes that you set `@Nullable`; so maybe your case is already solved.

Comment: Yes, using a default is the only way to let an analysis tool detect the missing Nullable. Applying the default indicates: I don't want to allow the original Java semantics where "String" says: "it's OK to assign null" *and* "it's OK to dereference without check". In Eclipse you would, as a last step, enable the check for *missing* NonNullByDefault.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. IntelliJ Idea has static code analysis tool. You can find instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/static_code_analysis.html).

EDIT: You can also run all inspections for your code in Idea (look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections.html)), or in offline mode with command line tools (look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections-offline.html)).

Comment: See my comment under the question.

Comment: Added some useful links in my answer that may help you.

Comment: How exactly would you use IntelliJ to solve the OP's case? I believe it can't be done - but I'd love to see that I'm wrong!

Comment: We use IntelliJ inspection tools in our continuous integration. Everytime anybody makes a commit to our repositoty, code is analyzed for inspections with  command line tool. And (among many other inspections) if any method that can return null (and marked as `@Nullable`) is used without checking its result for null, inspection appears. It's very useful and helpful. Or maybe I understood you wrong. What do you mean by OP's case?

Comment: You describe how it is a good thing to have properly annotated methods, but the [OP](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253162/1005481) was asking how to ensure that all methods are annotated properly.

Comment: Sorry for a bit misunderstanding. But the thing is: IntelliJ annotations can do that too. In our work code it is very strict that every method must have either `@NotNull` or `@Nullable` annotation. If it doesn't have any annotation, inspection is shown (that annotation is required). If it has `@NotNull` annotation, but can return `null`, inspection is shown. If it has `@Nullable` annotaion, no inspections are shown. So you can check your entire project code for these cases: all methods are annotated, `@Nullable` methods results are checked before using, `@NotNull` methods can't return `null`.

Comment: Which inspection exactly is it that you use to require all methods to be annotated?

Comment: There are 2 inspections: "NotNull/Nullable problems" and "Constant conditions & exceptions".
1. You need to add <idea install dir>/lib/annotations.jar library
2. Go to File -> Settings -> Inspections
3. Enable these two inspections
4. In "Constant conditions..." enable checkbox "Suggest @Nullable annotaion for methods that may possibly return null..."
5. That's it :)

Comment: That's already quite useful. But it works only if the value is *probably* `null`, and it will not enforce every method to be annotated. If the example said `return "foo";`, you wouldn't get a message. Also, it doesn't flag methods if it's not sure whether they return `null`.

Comment: Yeah, I lied a little bit. Forcing every method to have annotation is our custom inspection (in our team i mean). But OP's original question can be totally solved with these 5 steps